# static member object linking error

Tags: c++

I am getting linking error when I build the project. I have a static member pointer which I am setting from a static member function. Any ideas what's the problem

```
class Logger
{

 private:   
  static MyComp* pComp;
 public:    
  static void setComp(MyComp* comp);
      // more methods ..
};  

void Logger::setComp(MyComp* comp)

{   
pComp = comp; 
}
```

Get the linking error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "Logger::pComp", referenced from:
>         Logger::setComp(MyComp*) in Logger.o

Comment: Don't you mean `pComp = comp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add

```
  MyComp* Logger::pComp;
```

to your cpp file (outside the class declation).

Comment: that worked, thanks why is it needed anyway ?

Comment: @Ahmed Because `static void setComp(MyComp* comp);` is a declaration, not a definition.

Answer (score 0):

In order to initialize a static data-member we must include a formal definition outside the class.